# Vertx Instance not initialized when using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to writer an HTTP server using a `Vert.x` `CoroutineVerticle`, but I get an error `lateinit property vertxInstance has not been initialized`. It seems like the `init(...)` function of `CoroutineVerticle` is not being called when the verticle is deployed.

```
package http

import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.kotlin.core.http.listenAwait
import io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineVerticle

class CoTest : CoroutineVerticle() {
    private var router = createRouter()

    override suspend fun start() {

        vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router)
            .listenAwait(config.getInteger("http.port", 8182))
    }

    private fun createRouter() = Router.router(vertx).apply {
        get("/favicon.ico").handler { req ->
            req.response().end("NO")
        }
    }
}
fun main() {    
    class V : ServerVertxCo(8182) {}
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(CoTest::class.java.canonicalName)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order you do things in your class.

The order for vertx is:

1. Create the vertx instance
2. Deploy a verticle
3. Verticle class constructor is called (vertx is not "injected" to it yet)
4. Vertx does some internal initializations
5. Vertx calls the verticle's `start` function

You use `private var router = createRouter()` in the class (outside the `start` block) and at that point `vertx` is not "injected" yet to the class so you get an exception.

If you move it to the `start` block it should work as you expect:

```
class CoTest : CoroutineVerticle() {

  override suspend fun start() {
    val router = createRouter()

    vertx.createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(router)
      .listenAwait(config.getInteger("http.port", 8182))
  }

  private fun createRouter() = Router.router(vertx).apply {
    get("/favicon.ico").handler { req ->
      req.response().end("NO")
    }
  }
}

suspend fun main() {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  vertx.deployVerticleAwait(CoTest::class.java.canonicalName)
}
```

Comment: Thank! The server is up and working now. I changed router to a `lateinit var` assigned from inside start because I needed runtime access to the router.